# Scala code that works in IntelliJ fails in Scala's REPL

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I see the following when I type this one-liner in Scala's REPL, but it works fine in IntelliJ. What is going on?

```
scala> def sum[T: Numeric](seq: Seq[T]): T =  if (seq.size == 1) seq.head else seq.head + sum(seq.tail)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[T]
 required: Seq[String]
       def sum[T: Numeric](seq: Seq[T]): T =  if (seq.size == 1) seq.head else seq.head + sum(seq.tail)
                                                                                                  ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do an import `import Numeric.Implicits._` for Scala to identify that `+` as a `Numeric` addition. With the import it works in the console as well:

```
scala> import Numeric.Implicits._
import Numeric.Implicits._

scala> def sum[T: Numeric](seq: Seq[T]): T =  if (seq.size == 1) seq.head else seq.head + sum(seq.tail)
sum: [T](seq: Seq[T])(implicit evidence$1: Numeric[T])T
```

Without the import Scala tries to use the `+` method defined in the implicit class `Predef.any2stringadd`. This class is defined in `Predef`, so it's imported automatically into any Scala code. It converts the first argument of any type to a `String`, and expects the second argument to be a `String`. In your case it's not a `String`, thus the error message.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, your Intellij-IDEA seems to ignore the missing import of the implicit conversions (it could be the behavior specified by Intellij, or it could be some import that you omitted in your question).

This here works in the Scala REPL, and also keeps the scope of the implicit conversions to a minimum:

```
def sum[T](seq: Seq[T])(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = { 
  import num._
  if (seq.size == 1) seq.head else seq.head + sum(seq.tail) 
}
```

Comment: The other way around - it worked for me in IntelliJ but not in the REPL.

Comment: @Frank What is "the other way around"? The above code snippet definitely works in the scala repl.

Comment: Yes, mine didn't work in the REPL, because I was not importing `num` properly. That is my answer. Kolmar nailed it when he pointed out I missed the importing of `num`.

Comment: Also, of course, in my file in IntelliJ, I _was_ importing `num` correctly, but I forgot to add that in the REPL :-(